# How to remove escaped double-quotes inside a string in Common Lisp?

Tags: string, common-lisp

Running `(cl-json:encode-json-to-string 'ctx)` gives `"\"ctx\""`

I need `"ctx"` not `"\"ctx\""`.

I could use cl-ppcre and remove matching double-quotes inside the string.
However, this seems like overkill. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If you do not want json-encoded strings, why do you json-encode them?

Comment: There are more than one thing that need encoding.

Comment: Maybe, but it doesn't seem like _JSON_ encoding.

Comment: Maybe that's true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does `gives "\"ctx\""` mean?

Common Lisp uses the `\` as a escape character during printing results.

The string itself has five characters:

```
CL-USER 12 > (describe "\"ctx\"")

"\"ctx\"" is a SIMPLE-BASE-STRING
0      #\"
1      #\c
2      #\t
3      #\x
4      #\"
```

You can print the string contents:

```
CL-USER 11 > (write-string "\"ctx\"")
"ctx"
"\"ctx\""
```

You can also remove the first and last characters:

```
CL-USER 10 > (subseq "\"ctx\"" 1 (- 6 2))
"ctx"
```

You can also trim all surrounding `"` characters:

```
CL-USER 13 > (string-trim "\"" "\"ctx\"")
"ctx"

CL-USER 14 > (string-trim '(#\") "\"ctx\"")
"ctx"
```

String trim takes a sequence of characters as the first argument: the characters to remove. The second argument is the string.

Note that it will remove all such characters from front and back:

```
CL-USER 15 > (string-trim "\"" "\"\"\"\"ctx\"\"\"\"\"\"\"")
"ctx"
```

Comment: Question is about "How to remove escaped double-quotes inside a string". The answer is about how to trim the string. Downvoted the OP as well.

Comment: @mihai: no, that's wrong. The double-quotes are not escaped in the string itself. It's just that Lisp prints them so, if wished.